# Are these points singular?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be an algebraic variety over, say, some algebraically closed field. Consider a point in the intersection of two irreducible components. Is this point always singular? If yes, can you prove me why it is?

Comment: Please accept your older questions.

Comment: Which older questions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, a point is nonsingular if and only if the local ring at that point is a regular local ring, and at the intersection of two irreducible components, the local ring won't be an integral domain even.